# C# Designer overwrites ComboBox DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to set the DataSource of a ComboBox programmatically in InitializeComponent.

```
this.comboBox1.DataSource = (IEnumerable<> from a Linq command);
```

I save the file, everything works fine.  However, as soon as I open the Designer, it overwrites my code.  What should I set in the Properties page to prevent Designer replaces my code with:

```
this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange( new object[] {
    "value1",
    "value2",
    ...
}
```

where the hardcoded list is the result of the Linq command.  Since the DataSource is set in an early line, the Designer throw exception complaining "DataSource cannot be changed after it's set".

What should I specify on the Properties to prevent this from happening?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you notice the comment saying `Do not change the contents of this method in the code editor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be editing InitializeComponent manually. Instead, you should put that code in the constructor (or Load event) of your form/control.